# Executing procdump64.exe remotely using wmic

Tags: powershell, wmic, procdump

I am trying to generate a dump file using procdump64.exe in Powershell. I need to run the executable remotely using wmic. I am running the following command:

`wmic /node:[IP Address] /user:"[DOMAIN/USER]" /password:"[PASSWORD]" process call create "cmd.exe /c U:\procdump64.exe -ma U:\lsass.exe > C:\dump.dmp"`

For reference, I have verified that both procdump64.exe and lsass.exe are located at U:\ .

I receive output that says "Method execution successful" with a Return Value of 0.

However, the file that is generated is empty. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my command?

Comment: PowerShell has access to WMI/CIM directly (i.e., you do not need to use wmic if you have PowerShell).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately for the specific lab I'm working on I have to use this technique to get practice with it.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why would you have to use wmic if you have PowerShell?